# Custom Silverlight progress bar control with rounded corners

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls, rounded-corners

I'm planning to create a custom progress bar control, that supports progress sectioning. The final look will be:

[image: progress bar with sections]

I am comparatively new to Silverlight control development, so here is my idea and question:

1. I will be defining control's structure in XAML as an `ItemsControl`.
2. `ItemsControl` element will be bound to a data source, that will contain bar sections.
3. An `ItemTemplate` is going to define the way those sections are drawn.

The "trick" is, that the first and the last section should have a left and right rounded corners respectively. How can I define this constrain, so that the first and the last item from a source are drawn with rounded corners? Could I do it in XAML, or from code. If code, where do I inject the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a List of Border, take the first and last Border from your List and apply a corner radius.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:TestWpf="clr-namespace:TestWpf" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <TestWpf:AchievedConverter x:Key="AchievedConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="listBox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Bars}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Height="10" CornerRadius="{Binding Corner}" Width="{Binding Width}" Background="{Binding IsAchieved, Converter={StaticResource AchievedConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Bar> _bars;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        _bars = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();

        //Init
        _bars.Add(new Bar {Width = 20, IsAchieved = true, Corner = new CornerRadius(5, 0, 0, 5)});
        _bars.Add(new Bar {Width = 60, IsAchieved = true});
        _bars.Add(new Bar {Width = 80, IsAchieved = true});
        _bars.Add(new Bar {Width = 20, IsAchieved = false});
        _bars.Add(new Bar {Width = 50, IsAchieved = false, Corner = new CornerRadius(0, 5, 5, 0)});
    }

    public  ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars
    {
        get { return _bars; }
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public bool IsAchieved { get; set; }
    public CornerRadius Corner { get; set; }
}

public class AchievedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        else
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but the question is how do I "take the first and last Border from your List"?

Comment: I have attached a sample. It should help you.

Comment: As I said, the number of items will always be variable and bound to a collection. But you are advising to do rounding in code behind, in constructor of something. Well, ok, I will try and get back to the question. Thank you.

Comment: I have added a full example for you

Comment: I have added a Converter in order to display a different color for ended bars

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5153/discussion-between-steven-muhr-and-maxim-v-pavlov)